# Mysql lock read a single row for innodb

Tags: mysql, locking, innodb

Need help to lock reading(select) row

At second 1 : Terminal A

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM tbl_processor WHERE id=1 FOR UPDATE; /*Or using this statement : SELECT * FROM tbl_processor WHERE id=1 LOCK IN READ MODE; */
UPDATE tbl_processor SET content='Updated content';  #Original content was content='Original content'   
SELECT SLEEP(10); #Just to sleep for testing purpose
COMMIT;
```

At second 2 : Terminal B;

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_processor WHERE id=1;
#This will return result immediately with content='Original content'
-----> This is my problem... I do not want this statement getting not updated content. It should wait until the Terminal A process completed
```

Comment: Read about "transaction isolation modes".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the second transaction (terminal B) to obtain a share lock:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_processor WHERE id=1 LOCK IN SHARE MODE;
```

I suggest you review the relevant information in the MySQL Reference Manual here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Comment: Thanks ya... I got the answer