# PDO Lock Table Row INNODB

Tags: php, mysql, locking, innodb

I have a table where sensitive data is stored and need to take care, that only one session is able to read/write on a specific row.

My table has 2 coloumns
id (int) primary
amount (int) index

so I want to lock the table but only one row
something like

```
LOCK TABLEROWS `mytable` WRITE WHERE `id` = 1
```

im using pdo and startTransaction wont prevent other sessions to read/write due that time

i read the InnoDB Documentation but didnt get it to run

**EDIT:**

```
$_PDO->exec('START TRANSACTION');
$_PDO->query('SELECT * FROM `currency` WHERE `id` = '.$userid.' FOR UPDATE');  
//maybe do update or not check if
$_PDO->exec('COMMIT');
```

so thats all i need to do?

Comment: Use intention lock, e.g. `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking.html#innodb-intention-locks

Comment: But this wont block reads? thats what i need

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44440152/mysql-lock-read-a-single-row-for-innodb

Comment: check update please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you show will cause other sessions doing `SELECT...FOR UPDATE` to wait for your COMMIT. The locks requested by `SELECT...FOR UPDATE` are *exclusive* locks, so only one session at a time can acquire the lock. Therefore if your session holds the lock, other sessions will wait.

You cannot block non-locking reads. Another session can run `SELECT` with no locking clause, and still read the data. But they can't update the data, nor can they request a locking read.

You could alternatively make each session request a lock on the table with [LOCK TABLES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html), but you said you want locks on a row scale.

You can create your own custom locks with the [GET_LOCK()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock) function. This allows you to make a distinct lock for each user id. If you do this for all code that accesses the table, you don't need to use `FOR UPDATE`.

```
$lockName = 'currency' . (int) $userid;

$_PDO->beginTransaction();

$stmt = $_PDO->prepare("SELECT GET_LOCK(?, -1)");
$stmt->execute([$lockName]);

$stmt = $_PDO->prepare('SELECT * FROM `currency` WHERE `id` = ?');  
$stmt->execute([$userid]);

//maybe do update or not check if

$_PDO->commit();

$stmt = $_PDO->prepare("SELECT RELEASE_LOCK(?)");
$stmt->execute([$lockName]);
```

This depends on all client code cooperating. They all need to acquire the lock before they work on a given row. You can either use `SELECT...FOR UPDATE` or else you can use `GET_LOCK()`.

But you can't block clients that want to do non-locking reads with `SELECT`.